# Using JavaScript library installed via npm in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, django, npm

I have rudimentary experience with JavaScript, centered around predominantly using JQuery.

In a Django project I'm building, I typically import my JQuery code into a Django template like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/preloader.js"></script>`.

Now I need to use a JS library that's installed via `npm`. Specifically this one: [github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C](https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C). It's job is to compress user uploaded on the client-side before uploading them to the server. E.g. I can do `target_img.src = jic.compress(source_img,quality,output_format).src;`.

But how would I call this compress method in my template?

As in, where/how do I import it? Should I dump all the library's code in a separate file and import it via `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/JIC.min.js"></script>`?

If I were to do that, then why install the library via `npm` at all?

Like I said, my knowledge in this domain is rudimentary. Would be great to get an illustrative example that clears my concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node packages libraries, are usually bundled into a `public/bundle.js` file. For this you need a bundler like `browserify` / `webpack` / `rollup` etc.

You would also need to create separate bundle step with `npm` in your deployment pipeline, which would bundle all your js files into a `bundle.js` file.

---

However, if you don't a heavy js app, you can just put the `min.js` file somewhere in the static folders manually.

Comment: Just so that we're on the same page, you mean that if it's not too big, I can use practically the same way I've been importing my JQuery code?

Comment: @HassanBaig yes, this is what I mean in the last line